# jquery autocomplete | what's wrong with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

here is the url why it the autocomplete is not working?

http://code.chaabee.com/mahmed/jobber2/

please help :S

autocomplete code is in footer there..

Answer (score 3):

You're including jQuery UI **1.7.2** *and* **1.8.7** in the page, this is causing some issues (mainly a `.zIndex()` plugin method error)...I'd remove this jQuery UI 1.7.2 reference to fix this up:

```
<script src="http://code.chaabee.com/mahmed/jobber2/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also note that the jQuery 1.8.7 you're including works a bit better (more optimized) with jQuery 1.4+, same with validation, etc...if you can update I'd recommend doing to, to jQuery 1.4.4 and jQuery validation 1.7.

Comment: @ehmad - you have *multiple* issues with your site, I think you've made a false assumption that *one* thing is wrong...that's simply not the case.  This answer fixed the problem at that time, but since you added no code to the question and your site is constantly changing, you should ask a question *specific to the issue*, one that doesn't rely on the current state of your site's code (which won't be there for others later).

Comment: @ehmad - Currently you're still including jQuery UI components multiple times (though this isn't the error) and returning `<li>` elements, instead of the formatted JSON the autocomplete widget is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting, 'There should be no direct access to this script!', obviously the script is looking for 'POST' request and not 'GET' request.